# Display content of a button on a label on another WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a button that contains a count of data returned from a query;
upon the click of that button, a different WPF form opens (stored in a variable, never closed). I want both the button and a textblock on that form to contain the same data.

I am confused about databinding; since all tutorials only really explain databinding on the same form.

the button with the onClick

```
<Button x:Name="CounterBtn" ToolTip="Open Teller" Content="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" IsTabStop="False" Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" Click="CounterBtn_Click" />
```

Creating the CounterWindow popup, and store it's opened property

```
CounterWindow CounterWindow = new CounterWindow();
private bool CWindow_IsVisible = false;
```

Function that opens and hides the window:

```
        private void ToggleCounterWindow() {
            if (!CWindow_IsVisible) { CounterWindow.Show(); } else { CounterWindow.Hide(); }
            CWindow_IsVisible = !CWindow_IsVisible;
            return;
        }
```

Showing the Query Result:

```
CounterBtn.Content = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

Code Behind for the CounterWindow

```
    public partial class CounterWindow : Window, IDisposable
    {
        public CounterWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried something? Please provide a [mcve] and let us know which *particular* issues you have.

Comment: Have both windows share the same datacontext and then they can bind the data exactly the same.

Comment: Hi Kevin, do you have a beginners tutorial that explains this?

Comment: I suggest you to use **ref** or **out**

Comment: Give us some code please.

Comment: @Fimlore We really need at least a minimal code sample here. We need some specifics. Does the first window create the second window, for example?

Comment: Updated the initial question, I believe that ViewModels are the way to go. I'm going to get more into that and DataBinding; I know it exists, but up till now tried programming the Windows Form way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem isn't tied directly to data-binding. 
Take a step back, you simply want the same variable/value to be referenced in 2 different places.

There are many solutions to this problem.
Simplest thing that comes to mind is sharing the same object to both ViewModels.

In this example, the shared count you want to share will be a property on a bindable base object using the Prism MVVM framework (for brevity).

```
public class QueryResults : BindableBase 
{
    private int _count;
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _count, value); }
    }
}
```

Now, we can have both view models reference that object directly.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public QueryResults QueryResults { get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel(QueryResults queryResults)
    {
        QueryResults = queryResults;
    }

}

public class PopupViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public QueryResults QueryResults { get; }

    public PopupViewModel(QueryResults queryResults)
    {
        QueryResults = queryResults;
    }
}
```

So when you show the popup window, you can supply the MainWindowViewModel reference to the PopupViewModel.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public QueryResults QueryResults { get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel(QueryResults queryResults)
    {
        QueryResults = queryResults;
    }

    private DelegateCommand _showPopupCommand;
    public DelegateCommand ShowPopupCommand =>
        _showPopupCommand ?? (_showPopupCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteShowPopupCommand));

    void ExecuteShowPopupCommand()
    {
        var popupViewModel = new PopupViewModel(QueryResults);
        var popupWindow = new PopupWindow { DataContext = popupViewModel };
        popupWindow.Show();
    }

}
```

This isn't the optimal way of doing things.
I wouldn't reference/share the QueryResults class directly.
I would put it on a shared controller interface and inject that into the ViewModels constructors using containers.
But that is more advanced stuff that while required in production code isn't required to get you past this issue as you learn how to develop inside an MVVM application.